# Looping through an Array of coordinates to draw line on a html canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying too loop through an Array of coordinates to draw several lines on a html canvas.

It seems like each line is being drawn on top of each other and the line is not starting from a new coordinate in the loop.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("lineCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var data = [
      [
        [
          6.87462062085475,
          45.9746815056445,
          2494.80004882813
        ],
        [
          6.87473799526779,
          45.9772917433492,
          2517.48754882813
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          6.87473461365077,
          45.9772995683242,
          2517.2578125
        ],
        [
          6.8736121249999,
          45.9779670155837,
          2542.50024414063
        ],
        [
          6.87299210781629,
          45.9781103097697,
          2579.26586914063
        ],
        [
          6.87223679891952,
          45.9780976249557,
          2623.55834960938
        ],
        [
          6.87169006623871,
          45.9782141639712,
          2674.02709960938
        ],
        [
          6.87133154968397,
          45.9781620504641,
          2706.29272460938
        ],
        [
          6.87084326975906,
          45.9784539456999,
          2685.76708984375
        ],
        [
          6.87055838217719,
          45.9797052404885,
          2641.150390625
        ],
        [
          6.86775431929958,
          45.9838701463132,
          2541.81811523438
        ],
        [
          6.86677434685096,
          45.9850426033623,
          2518.7724609375
        ],
        [
          6.86471620539337,
          45.9859078090035,
          2482.7353515625
        ],
        [
          6.86083954284208,
          45.9857654302634,
          2422.5908203125
        ],
        [
          6.85678792479354,
          45.9856953809239,
          2334.52661132813
        ],
        [
          6.85371440538845,
          45.9861255880752,
          2300.64892578125
        ],
        [
          6.85374919591106,
          45.987623548574,
          2328.4541015625
        ],
        [
          6.85538813707532,
          45.9885247948691,
          2368.02124023438
        ],
        [
          6.8571299935713,
          45.9893949398974,
          2430.18969726563
        ],
        [
          6.85762330877777,
          45.9903535872519,
          2444.35400390625
        ],
        [
          6.85792368848341,
          45.991104963556,
          2470.85522460938
        ],
        [
          6.86062047783254,
          45.9926610042636,
          2358.318359375
        ],
        [
          6.86367918950193,
          45.9952411154904,
          2238.4580078125
        ],
        [
          6.86651311990744,
          45.9958393525819,
          2198.28515625
        ],
        [
          6.86802868822584,
          45.9967659531001,
          2163.53515625
        ],
        [
          6.86890726501023,
          45.9985394379416,
          2082.47192382813
        ],
        [
          6.86946764936131,
          45.9989288273475,
          2065.57006835938
        ]
      ]
    ];
var previous = [0, 0];

$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
  $.each(value, function( index, value ) {

    ctx.moveTo(previous[0], previous[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(value[0], value[1]);
    ctx.stroke();

    previous = value;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="lineCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ocrn9L13/

Comment: This appears to be working exactly as intended. The path's are just so close together that it doesn't appear to be adding anything else (Except for the first jump from 0, 0 to 6.87462062085475, 45.9746815056445

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many times you get some data from an external source and that information is not scaled to suit your rendering needs.

One way to help scale the data is to find the extent, ie the max and min x and y coordinates.

Once you have the extent you can scale it to fit any coordinate system.

Below is your code modified to do what I just described above. It does two passes over the data. The first is to find the min and max values of x,y. Once that min and max have been found, I calculate the range for x,y and then translate and scale the data to fit the canvas, rendering the points as I go.

Use the max range out of the x,y extent to normalize the coordinates and the min width, or height of the canvas to scale scale up (or down) to fit the canvas. You translate the minx,miny position to 0,0 before you normalise and scale. See code for the step by step process.

```js
    var c = lineCanvas;
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      var data = [
            [
              [
                6.87462062085475,
                45.9746815056445,
                2494.80004882813
              ],
              [
                6.87473799526779,
                45.9772917433492,
                2517.48754882813
              ]
            ],
            [
              [
                6.87473461365077,
                45.9772995683242,
                2517.2578125
              ],
              [
                6.8736121249999,
                45.9779670155837,
                2542.50024414063
              ],
              [
                6.87299210781629,
                45.9781103097697,
                2579.26586914063
              ],
              [
                6.87223679891952,
                45.9780976249557,
                2623.55834960938
              ],
              [
                6.87169006623871,
                45.9782141639712,
                2674.02709960938
              ],
              [
                6.87133154968397,
                45.9781620504641,
                2706.29272460938
              ],
              [
                6.87084326975906,
                45.9784539456999,
                2685.76708984375
              ],
              [
                6.87055838217719,
                45.9797052404885,
                2641.150390625
              ],
              [
                6.86775431929958,
                45.9838701463132,
                2541.81811523438
              ],
              [
                6.86677434685096,
                45.9850426033623,
                2518.7724609375
              ],
              [
                6.86471620539337,
                45.9859078090035,
                2482.7353515625
              ],
              [
                6.86083954284208,
                45.9857654302634,
                2422.5908203125
              ],
              [
                6.85678792479354,
                45.9856953809239,
                2334.52661132813
              ],
              [
                6.85371440538845,
                45.9861255880752,
                2300.64892578125
              ],
              [
                6.85374919591106,
                45.987623548574,
                2328.4541015625
              ],
              [
                6.85538813707532,
                45.9885247948691,
                2368.02124023438
              ],
              [
                6.8571299935713,
                45.9893949398974,
                2430.18969726563
              ],
              [
                6.85762330877777,
                45.9903535872519,
                2444.35400390625
              ],
              [
                6.85792368848341,
                45.991104963556,
                2470.85522460938
              ],
              [
                6.86062047783254,
                45.9926610042636,
                2358.318359375
              ],
              [
                6.86367918950193,
                45.9952411154904,
                2238.4580078125
              ],
              [
                6.86651311990744,
                45.9958393525819,
                2198.28515625
              ],
              [
                6.86802868822584,
                45.9967659531001,
                2163.53515625
              ],
              [
                6.86890726501023,
                45.9985394379416,
                2082.47192382813
              ],
              [
                6.86946764936131,
                45.9989288273475,
                2065.57006835938
              ]
            ]
          ];

      var minx,miny,maxx,maxy;
      miny = minx = Infinity
      maxx = maxy = -Infinity;
      data.forEach(dat => {
          dat.forEach(point => {
              minx = Math.min(minx,point[0]);
              miny = Math.min(miny,point[1]);
              maxx = Math.max(maxx,point[0]);
              maxy = Math.max(maxy,point[1]);
           });
       });
       var rangeX = maxx - minx;
       var rangeY = maxy - miny;
       var range = Math.max(rangeX,rangeY);
       var scale = Math.min(c.width,c.height);
       
      data.forEach(dat => {
          ctx.beginPath();
          dat.forEach(point => {
              var x = point[0];
              var y = point[1];
              x = ((x-minx) / range) * scale;
              y = ((y-miny) / range) * scale;
              ctx.lineTo(x,y);
           });
           ctx.stroke();
       });
```

```html
<canvas id="lineCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that all of your x-y coordinates are the nearly the same, they're all basically the same pixel location.